# Error in readRDS(file.rds)

Tags: r, bayesian, rstan

Summary:

I installed the **rstan** package, now I am facing this error:

> Error in readRDS(file.rds) : unknown input format

Description:

```
> traceback()
5: readRDS(file.rds)
4: is(obj <- readRDS(file.rds), "stanmodel")
3: stan_model(file, model_name = model_name, model_code = model_code,
stanc_ret = NULL, boost_lib = boost_lib, eigen_lib = eigen_lib,
save_dso = save_dso, verbose = verbose)
2: stan(file = fName, data = datalist, init = list(inlist), chains = 1,
iter = n.it, pars = c("f", "tau"), warmup = n.warm, seed = computerID +
1000) at functions.r#131
1: RunModel(11, myT, nu, lambda, rho, BDRi, Pars, computerID, n.it,
n.warm, getwd())
```

Environment:

- RStan Version: 2.16.2
- R Version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
- Operating System: Windows 10

Comment: `readRDS("file.rds")`?

Comment: @JanLauGe I get `Error in readRDS(input) : object 'input' not found` if I specify a non existing object. Something else might be afoot here.

Comment: from `?readRDS()` --- "`file` : a connection or the name of the file where the R object is saved to or read from." Are you trying to access a file by name (in your example, file.rds)? If so, you need to provide the file name in quotation marks, i.e. "file.rds" as in my previous comment. I don' think this has anything to do with `rstan`

Comment: What is the actual command you are entering to get this error?

Answer (score 3):

Please test whether this works:

```
install.packages('rstan')
library(rstan)

saveRDS(mtcars, file = 'test.rds')
readRDS('test.rds')
```

Works fine for me

Comment: If it was my answer that fixed your problem, please accept it by clicking the tick mark on the left

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved. I use **writeLines** command.

```
library(rstan)
scode <- "
     parameters {
       real y[2]; 
     } 
     model {
       y[1] ~ normal(0, 1);
       y[2] ~ double_exponential(0, 2);
     } 
     "
writeLines(scode, "mymodel.stan")

mymodel <- stan("mymodel.stan", iter = 10, verbose = FALSE)
```